# PostgreSQL - JSONB in WHERE

Tags: postgresql, casting

I have a field that is defined to be JSONB, though in reality it has just text (no, I can't change the type as a solution).

This query:

```
SELECT value FROM property WHERE id = 1;
```

returns this:

```
-[ RECORD 1 ]--
value | "IP"
```

Now, I want to query by this value e.g. SELECT value FROM property WHERE value = 'IP'. I tried several different casting (value::TEXT = 'IP', value::VARCHAR = 'IP') but they all return no results. What is the correct way to do this query?

Answer (score 1):

```sql
SELECT value
FROM property
WHERE value = to_jsonb('IP')
```

If you prefer casting `value` to string then you have to fix your right side and pass `"IP"` instead of `IP`. However if the right side is actually not fixed (i.e. values other than `IP` are possible) then you would have to properly escape it, e.g. for `A"B` the actual value would be `"A\"B"`. Thus I suggest my original solution (which takes care of that).

Answer (score 0):

Converting a scalar JSON value to text, isn't unfortunately as straight-forward as one might wish. Using `to_jsonb()` on the right hand (as shown in frekish's answer) side is probably the best solution.

If you are looking for alternatives, you can convert the JSON value to text, using the [`#>>` operator](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html).

```
select value
from property
where value #>> '{}' = 'IP'
```

`'{}'` essentially means "the top level value"

---

The problem with casting such a value to text is that the double quotes are retained. Another option would therefor be:

```
select value
from property
where trim('"' from value::text) = 'IP'
```